# PHP: HTML to DOCX

Tags: php, html, docx

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to convert HTML to DOCX file using PHP.
HTML comes from wysiwyg editor (with inline styles) and I want to be able to create a DOCX file from it.

Looks like PHPWord can do just some basic inline styles and other libraries don't support inline styles at all.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want docx? using just a `doc` file, and creating html inside can allow for styling

Comment: not really, care to explain "creating html inside" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can approach it like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=document_name.doc");

echo "<html>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
echo "<body>";
echo "<b>My first document</b>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

You can add inline styles like so:

```
echo "<h1 style=\"color:red;\"> Hello World! </h1>";
```

Comment: That's pretty cool. But can I do some magic like setting a header/footer using this approach?

Comment: Another problem is, the moment I edit and save this document, it creates folder with three files in order to keep it's formatting